# Thanks for the help people!

Tags: discussion

Recently I passed the reading and hearing section in my German B1 exam after approx 9 month of what predominantly constituted of self study. I'd like to thank every one who helped me and wrote careful answers to all these things. I would like to continue my understanding of German and post answers of higher depth in the German language here later on.

Special mentions : RDbury, Jonathan Scholbach, Guidot,  Huebert Scholnast, PlanetMaker.

Thank you so much guys and gals!

Comment: Congratulations! Nice :)